# How to compare date using filter in controller.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code. I don't want to use momentjs and want to compare the date with the below codes.

```
var i = $filter('date')(Date1, 'short');
var j = $filter('date')(Date2, 'short');
var k = j - i;
if (k<0) 
{
   return true;
}
else 
{
   return false;
}
```

I want to compare my Date1 with Date2 and want to display which one is greatest. But it's not working. So anyone can help me here.

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577172/compare-two-dates-angularjs

Comment: `return (Date2 - Date1) < 0`?

Comment: Not helpfull.. i don't want to code more in length.

Comment: The Comment from  hadiJZ is helpful but my suggestion is  Use Momentjs which handles all these things pretty good and Precise

Comment: can anyone modify this code??

Comment: Then you should Go through momentjs .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison

Comment: i don't want to use momentjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code. You need to use Date.parse().

```
var i = $filter('date')(Date1, 'short');
var j = $filter('date')(Date2, 'short');
var k = Date.parse(j) - Date.parse(i);
if (k<0) 
{
   return true;
}
else 
{
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var i = $filter('date')(Date1, 'short');
 var j = $filter('date')(Date2, 'short');
```

Now directly compares both of them withour any third variables else as abpve mentioned you need to use `parseInt`

```
 if (i > j) 
   return true;
  return false;
```