# how to compare two dates 29-July-2016 and 01-Aug-2016 in angularjs

Tags: javascript

`var startDateValuecmp = 29-July-2016;`  I have start Date Value in 29-July-2016.

`var endDateValuecmp=01-Aug-2016;`  end Date Value 01-Aug-2016.

I want to compare this formate of date.

```js
if (startDateValuecmp < endDateValuecmp) {
  if (confirm("Please Check Event Date And Follow Up Date!!! Do you want to continue ?") == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577172/compare-two-dates-angularjs)

Comment: AngularJs doesn't have anything to do with date comparisons.  JavaScript has a `Date` class, and there are other JavaScript libraries that can help with date calculations, but please don't make the incorrect assumption that AngularJs has anything to do with these calculations based solely on the fact that it's written in the same language.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass date to `Date` builtin JavaScript class and then compare it

```
var startDateValuecmp = new Date('29-July-2016');
var endDateValuecmp  = new Date('01-Aug-2016')

 if ( startDateValuecmp < endDateValuecmp )
 {
...
```

This will return boolean `true` or `false` based on condition.

This will return date in localtime zone, if concern about it use [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Refer this [MDN Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

### Update:

This can't be invalid. Press button to Run this code

```js
var startDateValuecmp = new Date('29-July-2016'); 
console.log("startDateValuecmp:", startDateValuecmp);
```

Comment: var startDateValuecmp = new Date('29-July-2016'); Invalid Date

Comment: var startDateValuecmp = new Date('29-July-2016');
            var endDateValuecmp = new Date('01-Aug-2016'); The two variable i am getting Invalid Date.

Comment: check Browser compatibility table in MDN link from answer, its supprted in IE, btw are you in 90's ?

Comment: which version of IE you are using ?

Comment: Version:11.494.10586.0

Comment: well I dont have that to check, however I dont care about IE.

Answer (score 1):

Angular can direclty compare data if the input is well formatted.

If they're date object just compare them directly without .getTime() using `ng-if`